# How to make AutoHotkey recognize the active window?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, windows-media-player, autohotkey

I remapped my wheel mouse for Windows Media Player.  The remap works unless I change to full screen mode.  Then AutoHotkey does not recognize it as the active window, and the remaps don't work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> will modify the volume, and will work in fullscreen mode as well. I'd map your mouse wheel to send those keys instead.

Comment: It is mapped to F8 and F9 for Windows Media Player, but it only works when it recognizes that Windows Media Player is the active window.

Comment: You can use controlsend to send it to the WMP window if it exists: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm